# Desenhar quadrado na tela usando cerquilhas (#)

Tags: python

Olá estou começando a programar em `python` e estou com dificuldade de fazer um exercício em que eu tenho que fazer um retângulo com "#".

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

while largura > 0:
    print("#", end = "")
    while altura > 0 :
         altura = altura - 1

    largura = largura - 1
```

Porém, eu consigo fazer a largura mas não a altura. Alguém pode me ajudar?

O retângulo deve ser preenchido por dentro. 
Por exemplo: Largura = 2 altura = 2 deve sair assim:

```
## 
##
```

---

O retangulo deve ser preenchido por dentro.Por exemplo:  
Largura =2
altura = 2  
deve sair assim:  
"##"  
 "##"

Comment: Angelo para o retangulo ser preenchido por dentro o meu primeiro exemplo ou o do @LuizViera já fazem isso

Answer (score 13):

Será isto?

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))
for _ in range(altura): # por cada linha
    print('#'*largura) # imprimimos a largura * #
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/cClgee)

Se quiseres imprimir o retangulo sem fundo (só as arestas) em python2 ou python3:

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))
rect = ''
for i in range(altura):
    for j in range(largura):
        if(j == 0 or i == 0 or j == largura-1 or i == altura-1):
            rect += '#'
            continue
        rect += ' '
    rect += '\n'
print(rect)
```

Ou seja se estivermos na primeira linha, `i == 0`, ou na ultima linha, `i == altura-1`, ou na primeira coluna, `j == 0`, ou na ultima coluna `j == largura-1` "imprimimos" um "#" senão imprimimos um espaço vazio

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/pDXafE)

Comment: Tem como fazer usando apenas while?

Comment: @AngeloSpinardi dá sim, http://ideone.com/UJLqIJ , está aí com while

Comment: Obrigado Miguel!!

Answer (score 13):

Outra possível solução (com flexibilização do desenho com parâmetros para a borda e preenchimento):

```
def desenhaQuadrado(altura, largura, simbolo = '#', preenchimento = ' '):
    print(simbolo * largura)
    for _ in range(altura-2):
        print('{}{}{}'.format(simbolo, preenchimento * (largura - 2), simbolo))
    print(simbolo * largura)

print('Um quadrado:')
desenhaQuadrado(7, 10)

print('\nOutro quadrado:')
desenhaQuadrado(4, 8, '*', '%')
```

Resultado:

```
Um quadrado:
##########
#        #
#        #
#        #
#        #
#        #
##########

Outro quadrado:
********
*%%%%%%*
*%%%%%%*
********
```

Veja rodando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/yW0l1r).

Comment: Boa, o uso de função é boa ideia

Comment: @Miguel Eu só postei uma alternativa porque o AP disse que é pra estudo da linguagem. :)

Comment: Claro, também gostei da lógica

Comment: E o seu tem mais performance porque executado apenas num ciclo for

Comment: @Miguel Isso não é necessariamente verdade, pois o seu laço interno está implícito no meu uso do operador `*` aplicado ao preenchimento. :) Mas não que faça muita diferença de desempenho mesmo.

Comment: Luiz; muito cool! +1

Answer (score 5):

Uma abordagem simples:

```
width = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
height = int(input("Digite a altura: "))

for _ in range(0, height):
    for _ in range(0, width):
        print("#", end="")
    print("\n", end="")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
print ("#" * largura +"\n") * altura
```

Comment: Muito bom JJoao

Comment: @Miguel, obrigado. É a chamada versão preguiçosa :) . Já agora, aprendi umas coisas com a tua resposta.

Comment: acho que essa a maior razão para estarmos cá, isso e ajudarmo-nos uns aos outros

Answer (score 1):

Fiz assim:

```
def retangulo (larg,alt):
    carac = "#"

    for _ in range(alt):
        print(larg*carac)

larg = int(input("digite a largura: "))
alt = int(input("digite a altura: "))

retangulo(larg,alt)
```