# Dúvidas sobre funções em Python

Tags: python

Sou iniciante na área de programação e estou com dúvidas nas questões abaixo. Vou postar as questões e as minhas tentativas (todas estão apresentando erro no corretor). Se alguém puder me ajudar desde já agradeço.

> 1 - Escreva a função Retângulo, imprimindo os retângulos sem preenchimento, de forma que os caracteres que não estiverem na borda do retângulo sejam espaços.

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))
caractere = "#"


def retângulo(largura, altura, caractere):

    linha = caractere * largura

    for i in range(altura):
        print(linha)

retângulo(caractere, altura, largura)
```

> 2 - Escreva a função `n_primos` que recebe um número inteiro maior ou igual a 2 como parâmetro e devolve a quantidade de números primos que existem entre 2 e `n` (incluindo 2 e, se for o caso, `n`).

```
def èPrimo(x):
    fator = 2

    while x % fator !=0 and fator < x/2:
        fator = fator + 1
    if x % fator ==0:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def n_primos(n):

    lista_primos = []
    for i in range(2,n):
        if èPrimo(i):
            lista_primos.append(i);


    return len(lista_primos)
```

> 3 - Escreva um programa que recebe uma sequência de números inteiros terminados por 0 e imprima todos os valores em ordem inversa. (Mostrar a sequência na vertical)

```
seq = []
num = 1


while True:
    num = int(input("Digite o número: "))
    if num == 0:
        break
    seq.append(num)
seq.reverse()
print(seq)
```

Comment: Ok, quais são os erros para cada uma?

Comment: Ela mencionou "corretor" - deve ser um corretor automatico, do tipo "SPOJ": esse tipo de programa não fala qual é o erro  -  só fala que "deu errado" mesmo.

Comment: Olá Monica, bem vinda ao SOPT. A sua pergunta está ampla demais. Eu sugiro que você abra uma pergunta para cada um dos seus exercícios (vc pode editar essa e deixar só um deles, e abrir novas perguntas para os outros dois). Além disso, procure explorar *a sua dificuldade*: postar o código como vc fez é ótimo, mas indique e explique o que não está funcionando como esperado.

Comment: Ah, e a primeira parte da sua pergunta é duplicata desta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178560/desenhar-quadrado-na-tela-usando-cerquilhas

Comment: Obg a todos que se prontificaram a ajudar. Sou nova aq no SOPT e estou me acostumando ainda em como funciona as postagens. Vi o link que o amigo postou, realmente é bem parecida com o que procuro. Acredito que conseguirei resolver o problema la. Grata.

Comment: @Monica  - eu restaurei a pergunta para re0-incluir as duvidas que voce solucionou - afinal, já havia uma resposta fazendo referência a elas. 

Ao fazer perguntas, conforme voce for identificando os erros, evite editar a questão em si - senao as respostas ficam sem sentido.  (Nesse caso era algo até simples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua pergunta já é um pouco antiga, mas vamos lá.

## Programa 1

O primeiro programa tem o seguinte erro:

```
def retângulo(largura, altura, caractere):
# ...
retângulo(caractere, altura, largura)
```

Observe os parâmetros passados. Estão na ordem errada! Deveria ser `retângulo(largura, altura, caractere)`.

O segundo problema é que você vai pintar um retângulo cheio, e não apenas as bordas. Para corrigir isso, o processo é um pouco mais complicado:

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
print("")
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))
print("")
caractere = "#"

def retângulo(largura, altura, caractere):

    linha_cheia = caractere * largura
    if largura > 2:
        linha_vazia = caractere + (" " * (largura - 2)) + caractere
    else:
        linha_vazia = linha_cheia

    if altura >= 1:
        print(linha_cheia)
    for i in range(altura - 2):
        print(linha_vazia)
    if altura >= 2:
        print(linha_cheia)

retângulo(largura, altura, caractere)
```

A ideia aqui é computar `linha_cheia` que é a linha com `largura` caracteres `#` e `linha_vazia` que é a linha que tem um `largura - 2` espaços no meio seguidos por um `#` e precedidos por um `#`. Depois, eu coloco uma linha cheia, `altura - 2` linhas vazias e outra linha cheia.

Uso os `if`s para lidar com os casos especiais onde a largura poderia ser pequena demais para que uma linha possa ter espaços no meio ou a altura poderia ser pequena demais para o caso de poder nem ter uma (ou as duas) linhas cheias no começo e no final.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/4pKCfW)

## Programa 2

Primeiramente, `èPrimo` deveria ter sido grafado como `éPrimo`. Ou melhor ainda, `é_primo` ([veja as convenções de nomenclatura do Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)).

O segundo ponto é que na função `n_primos`, você não precisa manter uma lista de primos para depois dizer qual é o tamanho da lista. Basta você ir contando os elementos que são primos, sem precisar armazená-los.

O terceiro ponto é que na função `é_primo`, você não precisa seguir com o `while` até `x / 2`, basta ir até a raiz quadrada do `x`. Uma forma simples e fácil de saber se você chegou até a raiz quadrada sem precisar invocar uma função que calcule a raiz quadrada é usar como condição `fator * fator <= x`.

O quarto ponto é que você pode colocar o `if` que tem o `return False` dentro do `while`, e assim você não precisa repetir a condição do `%` tanto no `while` quanto no `if`.

O quinto ponto é que na sua função `n_primo`, você tem que usar `n + 1` no seu `range` ao invés de `n`. Isso é porque o segundo parâmetro do range seria o primeiro valor que está fora do intervalo, e não o último valor que está dentro dele.

Assim sendo, eis como fica o seu código:

```
def é_primo(x):
    fator = 2
    while fator * fator <= x:
        if x % fator == 0:
            return False
        fator = fator + 1
    return True

def n_primos(n):
    contagem_primos = 0
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        if é_primo(i):
            contagem_primos = contagem_primos + 1
    return contagem_primos

# Teste
for t in range(0, 100):
    print("p(" + str(t) + ") = " + str(n_primos(t)))
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/LX5Gmo) Obviamente, o teste dado não é parte do programa, é só para se certificar que ele funciona.

## Programa 3

Neste programa aqui, a única coisa que falta é imprimir na vertical. Isso é fácil, basta iterar a sequência com um `for` e dar um `print` em cada elemento. Segue o código:

```
seq = []
num = 1

while True:
    num = int(input("Digite o número: "))
    if num == 0:
        break
    seq.append(num)
seq.reverse()
print("")
for i in seq:
    print(i)
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/91FdHP)

## Observações finais

Alguns corretores não gostam de ver strings como `"Digite a largura: "`, `"Digite a altura: "` e `"Digite o número: "` na saída. Se for este o seu caso, apenas leia da entra sem falar nada ao usuário usando apenas `input()` e remova as linhas que tem apenas `print("")` dos programas 1 e 3.

Answer (score 1):

Para que o quadrado seja preenchido totalmente por "#"

```
largura = int(input("Digite a largura: "))
print("")
altura = int(input("Digite a altura: "))
print("")
caractere = "#"

def retângulo(caractere, largura, altura ):

    linha_cheia = caractere * largura
    if largura > 2:
        linha_vazia = caractere + ("#" * (largura - 2)) + caractere
    else:
        linha_vazia = linha_cheia

    if altura >= 1:
        print(linha_cheia)
    for i in range(altura - 2):
        print(linha_vazia)
    if altura >= 2:
        print(linha_cheia)

retângulo(caractere, largura, altura)
```

Answer (score 0):

Programa 1: você preenche o retângulo totalmetne preenchido, e não com o interior do retângulo em branco

Programa 2: Sua função de verificação não testao proŕprio númerio "n" - vai dar errado quando n for primo.

Programa 3: O enunciado pede para imprimir "na vertical" - eu entendedo isso como um número em cada linha - sozinho (sem vírgulas ou outros símbolos)-  você está imprimindo a lista de Python - a representação da lista é em uma única lina e e inclui colchetes e vírgulas.

Comment: Olá, as duas últimas consegui resolver, minha dúvida agora é na questão do retângulo. O meu código apresenta todo preenchido e o que o exercício pede é mostre apenas as bordas e espaços em branco no interior.

Comment: Isso  - com o comando "if", e um pouco de operações básicas você deve conseguir

Comment: Outra coisa-  se a resposta servir para voce arrumar partes do seu problema - não apague os problemas da pergunta - essa plataforma arquiva as perguntas e respostas   uma sem a outra não faz sentido.

Comment: Ah ok. Não sabia, tentei apagar as duas últimas para deixar o post mais especifico.

Comment: @Mônica - tentou construir sua função que gera retângulo usando o comando "if" para tentar fazer só as bordas serem impressas? O problema é simples, mas por aqui não gostamos de dar respostas prontas que vão impedir as pessoas de aprender.  Se ainda tiver dúvidas, crie uma nova pergunta com suas tentativas para a função retângulo correta.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre o retângulo, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
largura = int(input('digite a largura: '))
altura = int(input('digite a altura: '))
l = 1 
a = 1 #Primeira linha
while a <= altura: #Primeira linha
   print('#' * largura, end = '') #Linha completa
   print() #Nova linha
   a = a + 1 #Sai da primeira linha
   while a > 1 and a < altura: #Começa linha vazada
      print('#' + ' ' * (largura - 2) + '#') #Linha vazada até a penúltima linha
      a = a + 1 #Passa pra nova linha. Quando chegar à última linha, sai do while interno e volta ao while externo imprimindo uma linha cheia.
```

Esse é o código completo que imprime o retângulo vazado. Para imprimir somente o retângulo cheio, retire o while interno.

Comment: Se você remover o `end = ''` do primeiro `print` não precisará chamá-la de novo com `print()` para quebrar a linha.

Comment: Bem observado, Anderson. Obg.