# desenhar retângulo com hastags e perguntar novamente

Tags: python

Olá, estou tentando fazer esse código funcionar da seguinte maneira:
você diz a largura e altura e depois ele completa com as devidas "#" e depois ele perguntaria novamente e continuaria assim até a pessoa fechar o programa.

Porém ocorre um pequeno erro quando finaliza o desenho dos "#". Ocorre de ter mais um # entre a figura mostrada e a pergunta seguinte. Eu fiz um teste e descobri que se eu tirar o **"="** da *linha 9* `em coluna<=altura` o erro para de existir mas a pergunta que deveria ser feita em seguida não ocorre. alguém saberia me explicar por favor?

```
def retangulo(x,y):
  linha=1
  coluna=1

  while coluna<=altura:#4
    while linha<=largura:#3
      print("#",end=" ")
      linha = linha +1
    if coluna<=altura:
      print()
      linha=2
      print("#",end=" ")
      coluna = coluna + 1

largura = int(input("coloque a largura: "))
altura = int(input("Coloque a altura: "))

while largura>0 or altura>0:
  if retangulo(largura,altura):
    print(retangulo(largura,altura))
  print()
  print()
  largura = int(input("coloque a largura: "))
  altura = int(input("Coloque a altura: "))
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Desenhar quadrado na tela usando cerquilhas (#)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178560/desenhar-quadrado-na-tela-usando-cerquilhas)

Answer (score 0):

Como o seu código tem funcionamento cíclico (pergunta a altura e a largura de um retângulo e imprime-o infinitamente), você pode simplesmete iniciar um laço `while True`, que ficará se repetindo infinitamente.

Neste laço, você pedirá a ao usuário a largura e a altura do retângulo que será mostrado, e em seguida, chamará a função `retangulo(largura, altura)` criada por você, que recebe como parâmetros a largura e a altura do retângulo a ser impresso.

Nesta função `retangulo(largura, altura)`, iremos imprimir `#`  'largura' vezes. Por exemplo, se a largura for de 5, imprimiremos `# # # # #`. Porém, dentro de um laço de repetição `for`, que determinará a quantidade de vezes que essa linha será impressa, que é a quantidade de linhas (altura) do retângulo, conforme o código a seguir.

```
def retangulo(largura, altura): # Função que recebe como parâmetros a largura e a altura do retângulo a ser impresso.
    for _ in range(altura): # Inicia-se um laço que repetição, que imprimirá uma linha 'altura' vezes.
        print('# ' * largura) # A linha a ser impressa é a string '# ' repetida 'largura' vezes. Podemos fazer isso apenas multiplicando a string pelo valor desejado.

while True: # O laço while True repetirá o código abaixo infinitamente.
    largura = int(input("\nColoque a largura: "))
    altura = int(input("Coloque a altura: "))
    retangulo(largura, altura)
```